# How can add custom modules to path in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a big project I'm trying to debug, but I cant seem to add directories for modules. It breaks on the first import with a lighting bolt then exits when I try to debug.

I clicked edit debug configurations and clicked browse next to environment variables. Under PYTHONBUFFERED=1 I added

PYTHONPATH=%~dp0libraries\telnet

Then when I click OK I can see it show up in the environment variable list, separated by semicolon. But when I click Browse again, it's NOT there in the list anymore?!

I need to add multiple libraries like this, how can I do this? Can someone provide me an example? Let's say I need to add libraries like libraries\telnet libraries\tty libraries\wrappers

Do I need to add each one separately, like PYTHONPATH=%~dp0libraries\telnet PYTHONPATH=%~dp0libraries\tty PYTHONPATH=%~dp0libraries\wrappers

Or can I add them all in one line? And why doesn't it work and disappears when I go back to browse?

Notr, Im not trying to install any modules, this is a project that comes packaged with custom modules and an interpreter and Im just trying to add directories so it recognizes them

Comment: Am I right in assuming your script runs correctly, but only PyCharm has issues correctly recognising your modules' code? Have you tried marking the appropriate directories in the Project treeview as 'Sources root'?

Comment: Try to use terminal to make a [soft link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56339/how-to-create-a-soft-or-symbolic-link) for the library?